# Excel 2011 - How can I change this VBA UDF to output numbers out to do decimal places (hundredths place)?

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, excel-2011, vba

I'm trying to manipulate this UDF so the output shows the decimal values out to the hundredths place. Notice that the sum in cell G2 should read 30.50 (or 30.5) but its dropping the decimals. I've tried function CDbl and CCur, but doesn't seem to change output.

[image: textjoinsum digits]

Comment: Just noticed, Change Dim total as long to a double.

Comment: no need too as I should have caught that the first time, my bad!

Comment: next time, please post the code here instead of showing it in an image

Comment: I will do that when I get back to my computer.